# Stop counting playing on Soundcloud

Tags: api, soundcloud, playback

I would like to freeze the playlist counter. Is there any way to keep showing the play counter without increasing this number whenever a users clicks the play button?

Maybe another option would be to hide the playlist counter, but I am not sure whether the counter will keep registering every new playing.

Answer (score 0):

SoundCloud will unconditionally increase the the the number of plays a track has received when a user (potentially other than the user who created the track) clicks the play button. If for whatever reason you don't want this displayed, your best option would be to cache the response from `/tracks/[trackId] {track: { playback_count: n}}` when loading a particular track, and to never refresh this (and hiding the value displayed in a SoundCloud player widget). This will at least create the illusion that the playback count is unchanged, until of course, the user refreshes the page.